# Using NSolve with Plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Say I would like to solve the following equation for `x` using some parameter $k\in[0,1]$.

```
NSolve[x*(x + 2)/(1 + x) ==  k, x]
```

And plot the root `x` as function of `k`. Naively it would look something like this:

```
Plot[NSolve[x*(x + 2)/(1 + x) ==  k, x], {k,0,1}]
```

However, `NSolve` gives 2 solutions and I am only interested in a positive one, and would somehow need to specify increment of `k`.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: `Plot[x /. Last@NSolve[x*(x + 2)/(1 + x) == k, x], {k, 0, 1}]` ?

Comment: Wow, this actually worked as magic. Thank you very much, you can answer fully and I'll mark as solved.

Comment: Corey's use of a constraint in the answer below is conceptually better; I think you should go with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `x > 0` to `NSolve`; with it (contrary to using `Last`, or `First`, or `Part`) it doesn't matter which solution is positive or negative - it will always pick the positive one:

```
Plot[x /. NSolve[x*(x + 2)/(1 + x) == k && x > 0, x], {k, 0, 1}]
```

[image]