# Want a DiscretePlot of an NSolve that uses a parameter n

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Let's say I want to solve `f[n,R]==0` with respect to `R` for `n=1,2,3,...` (up to some upper bound) and put this in a DiscretePlot or something equivalent. Reading [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136271/using-nsolve-with-plot), I decided to try

`DiscretePlot[R /. NSolve[R*(R + 2)/(1 + R) == n && R > 0, R], {n, 1, 20}]`

as an experiment, which worked with no errors. But then when I try my example,

`DiscretePlot[R /. NSolve[Gamma[n/2, R^2] == 0.5 Gamma[n/2] && R > 0, R], {n, 1, 20}]`

a ton of errors are thrown in between some  time elapses, then an empty graph appears. For comparison, `NSolve[Gamma[20/2, R^2] == Gamma[20/2] && R > 0, R]` throws up a single error yet outputs `{{R -> 3.10946}}` in a fraction of a second.

How come the inputs for my situation aren't working even though the inputs for the other example are, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What version are you using? `DiscretePlot[R /. NSolve[Gamma[n/2, R^2] == 0.5 Gamma[n/2] && R > 0, R], {n, 1, 20}]` executes successfully with v12.1.1, 12.2, 12.3, and 12.3.1; I experienced problems with v12.0

Comment: Well that sucks. I'm using v12.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With v12.0 use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) rather than [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

DiscretePlot[
 R /. FindRoot[Gamma[n/2, R^2] == 1/2 Gamma[n/2], {R, (n + 9)/10}], 
  {n, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works.

Comment: An alternativ workaround for v12.0 is `sol[n_?NumericQ] := 
 R /. NSolve[Gamma[n/2, R^2] == 0.5 Gamma[n/2] && R > 0, R][[1, 1]]; DiscretePlot[sol[n ], {n, 1, 20}]`